# Insert multiple rows from single insert and select statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table d and table f

```
Table d
--------

id number
1   23
1   24
1   25
2   22
2   23
```

i need to insert into table f  like

```
INSERT INTO f 
 SELECT max(f)+1,
 (select d.number from d where number = 1),
 FROM f
```

table f needs to be

```
id   d.id      d.number
1     1         23
2     1         24
3     1         25
```

i have to select 3 rows and insert into that table with one select query.

Comment: Please add tag in which RDBMS (like Sql Server, Oracle, MySQL) you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please add more details? what will be the conditions that the rows should meet for it to be inserted in table f.

Comment: In your sample you mean `where number = 1)` or `where id = 1)` ??

Answer (score 0):

You just have to specify the correct column names in the subquery and outer query.

```
INSERT INTO f VALUES (id,number) (SELECT id,number FROM d WHERE id = 1)
```

And you can't refer to `id` and `number` in table `d` from f as `d.id` and `d.number` as foreign keys can't be set on non-primary-key columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using below sql query,

```
INSERT INTO f
VALUES
  (
    id,
    idNew,
    number
  )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber,
       d.id,
       d.number
FROM   d
WHERE  id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's set up your table definitions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b644c/1

```
create table d (id int, num int);
create table f (id int, d_id int, d_num int);

insert into d (id, num) values
(1,23),
(1,24),
(1,25),
(2,22),
(2,23);
```

Then this should get you the results you've specified.

```
insert into f (id, d_id, d_num) 
  select row_number() over (order by num), d.id, d.num
  from d
  where d.id = 1;
```

If you'd like to start the new `id` counter over for each of the existing ones, then include the `partition by` clause and leave off the `where` like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9906/1.

```
insert into f (id, d_id, d_num) 
  select row_number() over (partition by id order by num), d.id, d.num
  from d
```